# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'

Tags: module, distro

I am trying to install a library (https://github.com/yuanming-hu/taichi/) . I am running a script for installation(install.py). I am using python version 3.6+

I tried `pip install distro`. Still it's not working

part of code(install.py) :

```
        import distro
        dist = distro.id()
```

Error message:

```
File "install.py", line 184, in run
    import distro
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'
```

Comment: How did you run the `install.py` file ? `python3 install.py` ?

Comment: Yes I used python3 install.py

Comment: Can you try to install distro again, but this time with `pip3 install distro` ?

Comment: Yes It worked well!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pip3 install distro
```

This worked well for me.
Solution by : @Ugo T.

Answer (score 4):

For Debian/Ubuntu users, when you have the error:

```
command not found: pip3
```

you have to use `apt`:

```
apt install python3-distro
```